# cannot open file 'd3d9.h' - Windows 10/DirectX 9/VS 2015

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-c++, directx

Recently been trying to link needed include/libraries to my DirectX 9 project from the 'Microsoft DirectX SDK (June 2010)'. However when I compile I get the following: *1>LINK : fatal error LNK1104: cannot open file 'd3d9.h'*. **NOTE: I'm using Windows 10 with Visual Studio 2015.**

Here is what I have done so far with the project settings in order to link the necessary files.
1. In VC++ Directories I have linked the Include and Library(x86).
[image]

2. In Linker>Input>Additional Dependencies I have added the necessary header files from DirectX 9. These are d3d9.h and d3dx9.h.
   [image]
3. Here are my include statements. I only include d3d9.h and d3dx9.h from DirectX 9.

[image]

Comment: You won't link header files. You just [add their directory to the search paths](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/73f9s62w.aspx). Back to basics :/

Comment: The reason why I'm asking the first place is because I'm following a tutorial on a different Visual Studio version, where my code works fine. No need to be a douchebag about it...

Answer (score 3):

As @Youka said in his comment, you shouldn't be linking header files. You link libraries - and this doesn't vary between versions of Visual Studio. Instead of having `d3d9.h` and `d3dx9.h` in the linker settings, you will want instead `d3d9.lib` and `d3dx9.lib`.